# Three.js showing wire-frame when not enabled

Tags: three.js, webgl

Hi I hope you can help me will Three.js

I am using the following code

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: colour,
                                               wireframe: false,
                                               transparent: false,
                                               overdraw: false});
```

As you can see I have turned wireframe to false however it is still shown. Any Idea?

[image]

Comment: the screenshot is not good enough to evaluate the problem further. Is your object textured? maybe some other problems, can you show an example or the  live example of your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `CanvasRenderer` and you should be setting `overdraw` to `0.5` instead of `false`.

Comment: I have changed it to THREE.WebGLRenderer() and that fixed it